# Is this proof of irrationality?

Tags: proof-verification, irrational-numbers

Assuming a number is rational, then proving that this leads to a contradiction, is a powerful tool. I want to know if it can applied in the following case.

Assume a number $n$ is rational, with (fully reduced) form $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{even}{odd}$ for positive integers $\{a,b\}$.

Next assume another fully reduced fraction $\frac{c}{d}=\frac{even}{odd}$, and define $n$ as

$$n=\frac{a}{b}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{c}{d}.\frac{2^kk^{2k}}{(1+k^4)^k}$$
$$=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{even}{odd}.\frac{2^kk^{2k}}{(1+k^4)^k}$$

where $k$ takes positive integer values.

For positive integer $k$, it is obvious that $2^kk^{2k}$ is always even. However, $(1+k^4)^k$ is either even or odd depending on the oddness or evenness of $k$: for odd $k$, $(1+k^4)^k$ is even, and vice versa.

Given that we are looking at $\lim_{k\to\infty}$, evaluating $k$ for oddness or evenness becomes meaningless. Yet, deciding whether $\frac{2^kk^{2k}}{(1+k^4)^k}$ is $\frac{even}{odd}$ or $\frac{odd}{even}$ is vital to establishing whether or not integers $a$ and $b$ exist, thereby producing a rational value for $n$.

My question is, does this constitute a proof that there is no rational $\frac{a}{b}$? Or is it merely proof that the question is undecidable from these axioms?

**EDIT:**

As @Michael and @Saucy O'Path have commented below, $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{2^kk^{2k}}{(1+k^4)^k}=0$, which of course I should have spotted. However, my question remains valid, because now we have

$$n=\frac{a}{b}=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{c}{d}.\frac{2^kk^{2k}}{(1+k^4)^k}=0$$

But we have defined $n$ thus:

*Assume a number $n$ is rational, with (fully reduced) form $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{even}{odd}$ for positive integers $\{a,b\}$.*

The assumption demands that $n\ne 0$. But we have just proved that $n=0$. Does this contradiction constitute proof that $n\ne\frac{a}{b}$ and is therefore not a rational number?

Comment: It looks like you are defining $n=0$.

Comment: I don't quite know (yet) about your work, but most definitely $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac cd\cdot\frac{2^kk^{2k}}{(1+k^4)^k}=0$.

Comment: As you can see, your assertion about "whether $\frac{2^kk^{2k}}{(1+k^4)^k}$ is $\frac{even}{odd}$ or $\frac{odd}{even}$" being *vital* to determine the existence of $a$ and $b$ is unwarranted.

Comment: Substitute the second sentence of your post with "Assume $n$ is a female human being" and the third one with "Next assume that $n$ is Barack Obama". The new post has exactly the same issue as the current one, but since it's not about numbers it should raise fewer questions.

Comment: Thanks. It appears I have mis-expressed myself again, then. I have put "assume" where I should have put "I have an expression". I'll rewrite it.

Comment: Cancel the rewrite... $n$ exists and is not zero. That's not an assumption. The only question is whether it is rational or irrational. The other terms also exist, with the exception of $\frac{a}{b}$, which is the only assumption I made. And those terms (I thought) produce $n$. However, I'm clearly doing something wrong because the the limit of the $k$ term is $0$. So I'll go back to the drawing board.